# Changing default layout to not include all buffers

Tags: spacemacs

The default layout is fairly useless (for something effectively bound to the easily accessible '1' key all the time) due to the sheer number of buffers it can 'see'.

Is there any way to either:-

1. Make the default layout only see buffers which don't belong to any other layout.
2. Disable/hide the default layout (I can then create my own new layout which would work as above)

Comment: The variable `dotspacemacs-display-default-layout` controls whether the default layout is displayed at all.  Try setting to `nil` and defining your own custom layouts.

Comment: @AndrewSwann that variable controls whether the layout name is shown in the mode-line, it defaults to 'nil' anway. It doesn't influence whether it shows up on the list of layouts.